# How to count number of messages per half hour?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

Consider the following table:

```
msg_id  _time
-------------
1       13:32
2       13:56
3       14:05
4       15:00
5       15:17
6       15:28
7       16:40
```

I'm currently aggregating the number of messages per hour, as follows:

```
SELECT HOUR(_time) AS hour, COUNT(msg_id) AS cnt FROM messages GROUP BY hour 
ORDER BY hour
```

This results in a resultset as follows:

```
hour  cnt
---------
13    2
14    1
15    3
16    1
```

What I want, however, is the count per **half** hour:

```
hour   cnt
----------
13:30  2
14:00  1
14:30  0
15:00  3
15:30  0
16:00  0
16:30  1
```

What is the query making this possible? If necessary, I guess I could mkae a table with the half-hour times (00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, ... 23:00, 23:30), but prefer not too. (And I still wouldn't know how to use that table either).

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Why is the column still called "hour"? Maybe "time" would be more appropriate?

Comment: You might divide minute(_time) by 30 and group by that value in addition to hours. You might need to cast result to int, I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey! Have this solved your problem? If yes, please mark the answer that solved it as the correct answer to help others. If not, please give us feedback about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `case when`

```
SELECT COUNT(msg_id) AS cnt, CONCAT(CAST(HOUR(_TIME) AS CHAR(2)), ':', (CASE WHEN MINUTE(_time) < 30 THEN '00' ELSE '30' END)) AS hour
FROM messages
GROUP BY CONCAT(CAST(HOUR(_TIME) AS CHAR(2)), ':', (CASE WHEN MINUTE(_time) < 30 THEN '00' ELSE '30' END))
ORDER BY hour
```

Comment: Thanks! I've combined yours and aleroot's queries, because yours did show the half hours `10:30, 11:00, 11:30, etc.` in the resultset, but it didn't sort properly. The output was went: `0:00, 0:30, 10:00, 10:30` and I didn't quite understand how to fix that. So I cooked up `SELECT 
  CONCAT(CAST(HOUR(nyse_time) AS CHAR(2)), ':', (CASE WHEN MINUTE( nyse_time ) <30 THEN  '00' ELSE '30' END)) AS halfhour, 
  COUNT(tweet_id) AS cnt 
FROM tweets 
GROUP BY HOUR(nyse_time), FLOOR(MINUTE(nyse_time)/30)`

Comment: Very well, you've made it. To sort it in a better way, you have to sort by HOUR(_TIME) ASC, MINUTE(_TIME) ASC

Answer (score 4):

> I guess I could mkae a table with the half-hour times (00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, ... 23:00, 23:30), but prefer not too.

Yes, this is the correct solution if you are forced to use MySQL. Doing it another way is possible but can get messy and will be slower.

> (And I still wouldn't know how to use that table either)

Use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
    halfhours.start AS hour,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM halfhours
LEFT JOIN messages
ON messages._time >= halfhours.start AND messages._time < halfhours.end
GROUP BY halfhours.start
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was thinking, but looking at the other suggestions, it is possible in MySQL without a helper table :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try to group by in this way :

```
group by hour(_time), floor(minute(_time)/30)
```

Comment: Thakns! To also get `10:30, 11:00, 11:30, etc.` in the resultset, I used part of rcdmk's query: `SELECT 
  CONCAT(CAST(HOUR(nyse_time) AS CHAR(2)), ':', (CASE WHEN MINUTE( nyse_time ) <30 THEN  '00' ELSE '30' END)) AS halfhour, 
  COUNT(tweet_id) AS cnt 
FROM tweets 
GROUP BY HOUR(nyse_time), FLOOR(MINUTE(nyse_time)/30)`